# How to find a vector in $\mathbb{R^3}$ knowing its plane and certain of its projections

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Let $a=2i -j+ k$, $b =i +2i- k$ and $c= i + j -2k$ be three vectors. If the vector $d$ is on the plane of $b$ and $c$ and its projection on $a$ is of magnitude $\sqrt{2/3}$, find $d$

later: So I know that the dot product of cross product of $a$ and $b$ the $d$ is zero. But how do I find the projection on $a$ ? That was exactly where I was stuck.

Comment: @goblin could you just show me how it worksm I'm confused

Comment: c is not used here? Should that be the projection on c? Or is d a vector in the plane defined by a, b and c?

Comment: oh yeah!. It's my mistake, I edited it.

Comment: i think it is easier to project $a$ onto the plane $bc$ and figure out $d.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try setting out all the information available explicitly.

1. You know $d$ lives in the plane generated by $b$ and $c$. So $d=hb+jc$ for appropriate choices of real numbers $h$ and $j$.
2. Also, the projection of $d$ onto $a$ has magnitude $\sqrt{2/3}$, so $\|d \cdot \hat{a}\| = \sqrt{2/3}$. Where by $\hat{a}$, I mean $\frac{a}{\|a\|}$.

(An important mathematical principle is that if $u$ is a unit vector, then the magnitude of the projection of a vector $a$ onto $u$ is just $\|a \cdot u\|$. If $u$ is not a unit vector, we have to correct this formula: in this case, the magnitude of the projection of $a$ onto $u$ is just $\|a \cdot \hat{u}\|$. This is the version of the principle used above.)

So in summary, you should write:

$$d=hb+jc, \qquad \|d \cdot \hat{a}\| = \sqrt{2/3}$$

near the top of your page.

**Now spend some time struggling with the question.** Its a game; you just push symbols around your page, and when you've found the values of $h$ and $j$ (which are real numbers), you win.

(While playing this game, keep in mind that the vectors $a,b$ and $c$ are already known, so they can be "plugged in" whenever you want. I wouldn't plug them in straight away; see how far you can get using vector notation first).

Also, I would advise computing $\hat{a}$ before you begin.

Comment: thanks for replying. In addition to your methodology I used the property of cross and dot product special situations where      d.(bxc)=0. Which makes another relation between h and j. is that right?

Comment: Yes, that works because: since $d$ is in the plane of $b$ and $c$, and since $b \times c$ is orthogonal to $b$ and $c$, hence $d$ is orthogonal to $b \times c$, or in other words their dot product is $0$. You shouldn't *need* this, but you may certainly use it if it makes things easier for you.